# SQL query to find trend in fact table

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a fact table like below, how to find entities which values decreased over a given period of time?
For example, select entities and values which decreased between `2014-01-01` to `2014-01-04`

```
entity_id | value | date
12        | 15    | 2014-01-01 
56        | 21    | 2014-01-04
12        | 15    | 2014-01-04 
56        | 21    | 2014-01-02 
12        | 25    | 2014-01-02 
12        | 16    | 2014-01-03
```

For example, between dates `2014-01-01` to `2014-01-04`
value of entity_id 12 decreased twice:

```
entity_id | value | date       | old_value
12        | 16    | 2014-01-03 | 25
12        | 15    | 2014-01-04 | 16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(value) over (partition by entity_id order by date) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
where prev_value > value;
```

You can add `and date >= '2014-01-01' and date <= '2014-01-04'` for the specific date range.

Answer (score 0):

Range in MySQL is only < or > or =  you can combine them as you want but you still can use LIke  %date% to retrieve similar date you want

Answer (score 0):

Going to assume your table is called `entity`

```
SELECT e.entity_id, e.value as old_value, e2.value as new_value, v2.date
FROM entity e
JOIN entity e2 ON v.entity_id = v2.entity_id
AND e.date < e2.date
AND e.value > e2.value
GROUP BY e.date
```